# Acquiring an Active Q-Switched Laser

Tags: laser, electrical-engineering

I'm working on a senior undergraduate project in engineering physics, and I am building an instrument that will use a Q-switched laser as a short-pulse, low-pulse-repetition-rate light source. We need to be able to control the timing of the Q-switch, the light needs to be visible spectrum (< 750nm, preferably 523nm), and the maximum pulse width (FWHM) is 15ns. Power requirements are modest, as we are using it as a light source for a camera.

Can anyone provide some advice on buying cheap (< 1000USD) active Q-switching lasers or maybe converting an off-the shelf laser diode into a Q-switched one?

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/795/2451

Comment: Depends a lot on how much light you really need, what beam characteristics are required (temporal or spatial), and whatnot.  Rather than a classic Q-switched laser (ruby lasers baby!) with all that entails, you might consider a visible laser diode (or even just an LED) and a fast current pulse. You are not looking for long lifetime equipment it would seem, so you can overdrive the devices for a pulse, then let it cool for a while before the next pulse.

Comment: Cross-posted on Engineering: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/5557/16

Comment: http://www.findlight.net/lasers/solid-state-lasers/dpss